# Login user to facebook given email

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to prompt a user to login to facebook given their email (as in, I have the email already and want them to sign in with it)?

I have an app that asks the user for their profile page (https://www.facebook.com/USERIDHERE) and want to verify that the user actually owns the page they submitted. Really anything that accomplishes that goal would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is away to use the Facebook API for proper verification. You can go to there ssite amd read up on it, I believe they use OAuth2.

However, I'm a fan of lazy programming; so if you're not particularly concerned about security, you could prompt a user to enter the password, and programmatically try to login with the entered credentials and check the returned URL. If its Facebook's homepage the login failed, anything else would be considered verified as it actually entered the users account. Just don't go saving them passwords

Comment: Facebook deprecated an api a few months back that let me see a user's profile page :(

I'd rather not do the password thing for this, it's a bit too high profile for that.

Comment: You should not ask for the password because that is against Facebook Terms of Service and Facebook Platform Policy.

Comment: "Really anything that accomplishes that goal would be fine." Also, how are you planning to ask them to verify an account without prompting for a password? Anyone can give you a bogus email.